# How to use Jenkins for .NET builds

Tags: jenkins

We have a Jenkins server running on a Linux box and we are using it for Java projects (Maven builds).

We shall have a couple of .NET applications coming up. Shall I be able to build them on the Linux box? Do I need to add a windows box? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If these are .NET Framework (and not .NET Core) applications, the easiest way to go about it is to add a Windows box with everything you need for building your .NET apps (e.g. [install .NET Build tools](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48159)), etc. and then [setup a Jenkins slave on that box](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Step+by+step+guide+to+set+up+master+and+slave+machines+on+Windows).

Then on your builds for .NET, you specify a requirement to use the slave on the Windows box to build it.

N.B. Keep the Windows build node as clean as possible - i.e. Resist the temptation and do **not** install the full Visual Studio on it (!). Only install the SDKs you need.

Jenkins docs on .NET SDK - https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/dotnet-sdk/

Comment: Thanks @Caio for the quick answer. I shall go ahead to set it up.

Comment: Link for "setup a Jenkins slave  on that box" is dead.
Consider this link:  https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Step+by+step+guide+to+set+up+master+and+slave+machines+on+Windows

Comment: The current documentation url seems to be: https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/dotnet-sdk/